# PHP Contact Form Status Update in DIV

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Sounds like an odd question but here is what I have. The php has a snippet at the end that says success or failure makes a white screen to display this, I really want it to pop up right under the submit button on the same page rather than redirect the entire page.

I assume I could direct that to an empty `<div>`?

mail.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "art@jamisonsigns.com";
    $subject = "Web Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

With a simple HTML form on my website as follows:

```
<form class="contact-form" form action="mail.php" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
           <input type="text" class="name" id="name" placeholder="Name...">
      </fieldset> 
      <fieldset>
           <input type="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="Email...">
      </fieldset> 
      <fieldset>
           <input type="text" class="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone...">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
           <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
           <input type="submit" class="button" id="button" value="Send Message">
      </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: you'd need an ajax request, or completely re-build/re-issue the page with the form, including the mail status bit at the bottom of the new page.

Comment: You'll have to use jQuery (Ajax) to do a post back if you don't want to reload the page. There's plenty of information on how to do this, just google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit the form with Ajax. Then on success insert the message in the html.

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var formdata = $('#formID').serializeArray();
var url = '/urltopost.php';

$.ajax( 
{
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        //data: return data from server
        console.log("STATUS:" + textStatus + " | jqXHR:" + jqXHR + " | data:" + data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        //if fails      
        alert("ERROR:" + " -> " +errorThrown);
    }
});
```

});

[Here it is a tutorial if you need..](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)